# How do manga artists make a volume?

Tags: manga-production

A volume of manga an average has about 180-220 pages. A page of grey scale manga takes about 8-10 hours.

Comment: Welcome to A&M! Could you [edit] the question to make it a tad more specific? As it stands your question is quite unclear. Are you asking how a volume is determined? How the pages are made? How the artist deals with the workload?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question wasn't completely clear, so my answer may not be what you are looking for. That being said, I will tell you how volumes are 'made'.

As you may know, manga chapters are published in magazines on a regular schedule. An example of such a magazine is the *Weekly Shonen Jump*.

However, if a manga is popular enough, some of the individual chapters published in the magazine are collected and published into a single book. This book is a volume. Once there are enough chapters, another volume will be published.

Hope my answer helped you.